# Automated Phone calls in swift

Tags: swift, voip, phone-call

I am developing an app in swift in which when a customer places a order we have to notify the vendor about the order. So is it possible to call the vendor mobile through some api with a pre recorded message. More importantly will this app be accepted by the app store.

Comment: Yes VoIP based apps are acceptable by App Store.

Comment: Use pushkit and local notification. Then using VoIP call you can use pbx services for prerecord audio message.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS it is not possible to use the user's phone. You would have to use an API like https://www.twilio.com.

Answer (score -1):

Use pushkit with local notification to notify user about incoming call in foreground , background or terminated state.

Then there are many supporting platform to join in VoIP call.

References - 
https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification